# Несложная верстка дизайна

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Мне нужно сделать страницу как в iTunes store: [Ссылка на картинку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmech.jpg)

Я делаю так: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9AyXy/1/)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #222;
}
#album_page {
    background: #222;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#album_page .album_info {
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 30px;
}
#album_page .album_hr {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: 1px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(29, 28, 28, 0.91);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
}
#album_page .album_img {
    background-image: url('https://pp.vk.me/c5706/u84702241/a_1274e7c6.jpg');
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
#album_page .album_tabs {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
#album_page .album_tabs a {
    color: #8B8B8B;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#album_page .album_tabs a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#album_selection {
    margin-left: 75px;
}
#album_selection a.album_buy {
    border: 1px solid #F4F4F4;
    text-align: center;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="album_page"> <span class="album_info">
      <font color="gold">Альбом 1</font> <br/> 
        Год выпуска: 2009 <br/> 
        Количество песен: 12
        <span class="album_tabs"><a href="#">Песни</a> <a href="#">Отзывы</a></span>
</span>
    <div class="album_img"></div>
    <div class="album_hr"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="album_selection">
<a class="album_buy" href="#">Купить альбом</a>

    <br/>
    <br/>text</div>
```

Я не могу добавить помеченные блоки на страницу. Прошу вас помогите сверстать этот дизайн.

Comment: @Maqsood может вы все-таки добавите "помеченные блоки" хоть как нибудь... а-то это больше похоже на работу за вас.

Comment: @eicto, Я обновил ссылку, мой код правильно работает в браузере Google Chrome

Comment: и в firefox правильно работает, в чем тогда проблема ?